# How to setup a proper javascript path using path

Tags: javascript, url, text

I was wondering if anyone can help me correct this code.

I am trying to setup 3 different button menus using `var path = window.location.href;` for main URL, Russian site and Spanish site.

I seem to have 2 out of 3 working.

I am also sorry if I'm not the best at explaining this but below is what I'm trying to do. Hopefully someone can figure out what I'm doing wrong and help.

```
        var path = window.location.href;
        if (~path.indexOf("/ru/")){
            $j("#button1").append("<a  class=\"ru-text\" href=\"http://#/\">    <span>Отслеживание </span><br/>отгрузки</a>");
        }
        var path = window.location.href;
        if (~path.indexOf("/es/")){
            $j("#button1").append("<a  class=\"es-text\" href=\"http://#/\">    <span>RASTREAR </span><br/>ENVIO</a>");
        }
    }else{
        $j("#button1").append("<a href=\"http://#/\"><span>Track Your</span>    <br/>shipment here</a>");
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong `if-else` conditional, it should be as follows:

```
var path = window.location.href, linkEl = "";

if (~path.indexOf("/ru/")) {
    linkEl = "<a  class=\"ru-text\" href=\"http://#/\"><span>Отслеживание</span><br/>отгрузки</a>";
} else if (~path.indexOf("/es/")) {
    linkEl = "<a  class=\"es-text\" href=\"http://#/\"><span>RASTREAR </span><br/>ENVIO</a>";
} else {
    linkEl = "<a href=\"http://#/\"><span>Track Your</span><br/>shipment here</a>";
}
$j("#button1").append(linkEl);
```